# How to fix MetroMessageBox Title size display problem

Tags: c#, size, microsoft-metro, title, messagebox

I have strange problem of using MetroMessageBox. When typing title string of message box it cuts bottom of fonts like this:

[image]

My code is just declaration of MessageBox and it is used in simple WinForm:

```
MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Some message", "Notification g j p q y", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

In documentation ([link](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/tree/master/MetroFramework/MessageBox)) is maybe here problem (in file): metroframework-modern-ui/MetroFramework/MessageBox/MetroMessageBoxControl.Designer.cs:

```
this.titleLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(159, 32);
```

Comment: Have you got font zooming on? Settings, display, "make everything bigger"?

Comment: @Will sorry for numb question, where can I check this setting?

Comment: Start: Settings: Display (or, "Change Display Settings")

Comment: Flydog57 thanks, @Will yes this was a problem, but is it ok, that if user have bigger font, app and other elements (set in settings) that couse cut in title?

Comment: If you're saying that this was the cause of the text being cut off, then this is a bug and the developer of the framework will have to fix it.

Comment: @Will yes this was a cause of text being cut off. I test in two diffrent PC's (Win 10) same mistake appears